# Error report for execution and query intent in the test suite of the google action

Tags: deployment, error-reporting, google-smart-home, test-suite, google-assistant

Our project passed “Turn on” execution and query in the test
suite of the google action.
But “Turn off” execution and query failed and I couldn’t find in our part.
After “Turn off” execution, I responded “false” for “on” attribute but
error report was shown - actual state: {"on":true,"online":true}.
Below is the exchanged data and the error report.

**Google action request for execution:**
{"inputs":[{"context":{"locale_country":"US","locale_language":"en"},"intent":"action.devices.EXECUTE","payload":{"commands":[{"devices":[{"id":"eg_cam_87901"}],"execution":[{"command":"action.devices.commands.OnOff","params":{"on":false}}]}]}}],"requestId":"960820806239759768"}

**Our Response for execution:**
{"requestId":"960820806239759768","payload":{"commands":[{"ids":["eg_cam_87901"],"status":"SUCCESS","state":{"online":false,"on":false,"currentToggleSettings":null}}]}}

**Google action error report**
Turn off the bedroom
AssertionError: Expected state to include: {"on":false}, actual state: {"on":true,"online":true}: expected false to be true

**Google action request for query:**
{"inputs":[{"intent":"action.devices.QUERY","payload":{"devices":[{"id":"eg_cam_87901"}]}}],"requestId":"4409204964431192716"}

**Our Response for query:**
{"requestId":"4409204964431192716","payload":{"devices":{"eg_cam_87901":{"online":false,"status":"SUCCESS","on":false,"currentToggleSettings":null}}}}

**Google action error report**
Query after 'Turn off the bedroom'
Error: the string "Error from HA: deviceOffline" was thrown, throw an Error :) at new f (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18143:10) at Runner.fail (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:4491:11) at js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:4802:18 at done (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:4189:5) at js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:4236:11 at w.Ic (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18137:24) at r.run (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18129:169) at js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18171:310 at w.Jl (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18137:454) at r.Ms (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18130:301) at h (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18126:375) at y.Jl [as Ic] (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18139:326) at q (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18167:89) at e (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18158:235) at XMLHttpRequest.w (js/app_compiled.js?f77b3b67-f1c5-4a38-8a20-fe5eafbc2c40:18167:241)

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple issues here.

First, you need to verify that your sync response includes the appropriate device attributes - your execution/query responses both return `NULL` for your `currentToggleSettings` instead of the string of the `availableToggles` in your sync response. If you are just using `OnOff` for your device, you don't actually even need to implement any of the `Toggle` trait features. Again, verify what is in your initial sync response.

Second, you're returning `online: false` as well as `on:false`, which is why you're getting the following error:

> Error: the string "Error from HA: deviceOffline" was thrown

`online:false` should only be used when you intend to return the TTS response of *"the device is not available right now"* when a user issues a command/query, and when the device cannot be controlled. This should also include `status:ERRROR` in your response. You can read more about handling errors and exceptions in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/error-handling#example_1_error_response_for_execute_intent).

Returning `online:true, on:false` or `online:true, on:true` when responding to an execute/query request should fix the `deviceOffline` error.